# How to take the array element after sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a problem, How to take he array element after sent the form.
My objective is to save element created by language.
the return of $_POST is not clear form me to save correctly the date inside the bd.

example :

the form

```
 languages = 2; // en and fr

  for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($languages); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $content .= '
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="input-group input-group-option">
         <label for="lang" class="col-1 col-form-label">' . $OSCOM_Language->getImage($languages[$i]['code']) . '</label>
         ' . HTML::inputField('user_question[][' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', null, 'placeholder="Write a question"') . '
         <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
            <span>X</span>
         </span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This script allow to create a field when I click on a language (en for example)

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('focus', 'div.form-group-options div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
        var sInputGroupHtml = $(this).parent().html();
        var sInputGroupClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="'+sInputGroupClasses+'">'+sInputGroupHtml+'</div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'div.form-group-options .input-group-addon-remove', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

the post result

```
var_dump($_POST['user_question'])
        array(8) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_1" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_2" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_3" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(0) "" } 
    [4]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "test_fr_1" } 
    [5]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "test_fr_2" } 
    [6]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "test_fr_3" } 
    [7]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(0) "" } }
```

following below the answer, the good response;

```
  $N = sizeof($_POST['user_question']); // 4
  $M = sizeof($languages); // 2

  for ($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$M; $j++) {
      $language_id = $languages[$M]['id']+1;

      if (!is_null($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N]) ) {

        $test = (bool)array_filter($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N], create_function('$a','return preg_match("#\S#", $a);'));

       if ($test == true) {
        var_dump($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N]);
        var_dump('<br>');
       }
      }
    }
```

result

```
array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_1" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_2" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [1]=> string(0) "" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "test_fr_1" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "test_fr_2" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [2]=> string(0) "" } string(4) "
```

the problem how to delete this

```
 " array(1) { [1]=> string(0) "" } string(4) "
```

I tried  `$N = sizeof($_POST['user_question']) - 1` but does'nt work.
Thank you

Comment: Your inner `for` is overwriting `$n` on every iteration. Try using a different variable name. That probably still won't give you the result you want, but it's a start.

Comment: Yes, you are right, an error. I changed the code above but the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$N = ....; // some expression that gives the number of questions per language (3 in the sample data)
$M = ....; // some expression that gives languages (2 in the sample data)

for ($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$M; $j++) {
        var_dump($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, we are close:
" array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_2" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [1]=> string(0) "" } string(4) "
if I use :
$N = sizeof($_POST['user_question']) - 1; // 3 
the result become
" array(1) { [1]=> string(0) "" } string(4) "
" array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "test_en_2" } string(4) " is deleted.

Comment: Am I right in my assumptions that `sizeof($_POST['user_question']);` is 4, and `sizeof($languages);` is 2?

Comment: user_question can have 0 to x  elements and $languages can have 1 to x language. Now in this case, I have 6 user_question in total, 3 in english, 3 in french.

Comment: What do `var_dump($N)` and `var_dump($M)` give?

Comment: As far as I can tell, my loops are correct, but you need to devise expressions to give `$N` to be 3 and `$M` to be 2. I can't devise those expressions from the information I have.

Comment: this the complete result inside loop for 6 questions and 2 languages : 
var_dump($N) questions = int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) int(6) ------
and   var_dump($M)  language = int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2) int(2)

Comment: Find the solution : see above : $test = (bool)array_filter($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N], create_function('$a','return preg_match("#\S#", $a);'));

           if ($test == true) {

            var_dump($_POST['user_question'][$i + $j * $N]);
            var_dump('<br>');
           }